# Upgrading to v3.0 - found more issues (3)

Tags: highcharts

I have updated to v3.0 and found this issue in IE9 & Chrome.
I have a button that creates a new chart based on the data found.
The graph scale yAxis changes? (Note: the chart is logarithmic chart).
And sometimes the graph changes into:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should contact the people maintaining the project?

Comment: Have you live example?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not having a real example: but i noticed this when pressing the custom button (after 5/6 times) - this issue appears:

Notes:

1) The button is created with the chart.
2) The chart might updated every 5sec - if data was changed

```
// handle detailed chart refresh button
function showResetZoomButton(pb_detailed_chart)
{
    // load refresh images
    var ResetZoomJPG        = 'images/gallery/reset_zoom.jpg';
    var ResetZoomPressedJPG = 'images/gallery/reset_zoom_pressed.jpg';

    // add refresh (pressed) image
    var imgResetZoomPressed = pb_detailed_chart.renderer.image(ResetZoomPressedJPG, pb_detailed_chart.chartWidth-112,10,24,20);
    imgResetZoomPressed.add();
    imgResetZoomPressed.css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    imgResetZoomPressed.attr({'title':'Reset Zoom'});

    // add refresh image
    var imgResetZoom = pb_detailed_chart.renderer.image(ResetZoomJPG, pb_detailed_chart.chartWidth-112,10,24,20);
    imgResetZoom.add();
    imgResetZoom.css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    imgResetZoom.attr({'title':'Reset Zoom'});

    // init in-action/out-action for mouse event
    var inAction = "mouseover";
    var outAction = "mouseout";
    if ( $.browser.mozila )
    {
        inAction = "mouseenter"; outAction = "mouseleave";
    }

    imgResetZoom.on(inAction, function(){
        imgResetZoomPressed.show();
        imgResetZoom.hide();
    });

    imgResetZoom.on(outAction, function(){
        imgResetZoom.show();
        imgResetZoomPressed.hide();
    });

    imgResetZoomPressed.on(inAction, function(){
        imgResetZoomPressed.show();
        imgResetZoom.hide();
    });

    imgResetZoomPressed.on(outAction, function(){
        imgResetZoom.show();
        imgResetZoomPressed.hide();
    });

    // refresh chart
    imgResetZoomPressed.on('click',function(){
        // check if master found, and if real time disabled
        if (pb_master_chart && enable_lastRoundsChart_realtime == 0)
        {
            // master chart found
            // remove plotBand
            pb_master_chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('mask-before');
            pb_master_chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('mask-after');
            pb_master_chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
                id: 'mask-before',
                from: -1,
                to: 99999,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
            })
        }
        // reset detailed graph
        createDetail(cache_last_rounds.last_rounds_data, window.show_top_round_ids);
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's caused by animations? Try to disable them.